# Multiple CREATE TABLE in one script

Tags: mysql, sql

I am making a php setup page and looking to run an sql file on click of the submit button. Although, in the SQL file I have 2 CREATE TABLE and it will only work if there is 1 CREATE TABLE. Snippet below:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
username varchar(255) NOT NULL,
email varchar(255) NOT NULL,
password varchar(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE details (
  name varchar(255),
  server_ip varchar(255),
  store_link varchar(255),
  bans_link varchar(255)
);
```

php code:

```
  include("../config.php");
  $slashy = file_get_contents("setup.sql");
  mysqli_query($conn, $slashy);
```

Comment: add the php code you use to run the sql file

Comment: What happens when you run it with the two sentences? How are you calling that SQL from PHP?

Comment: added the php code to the original post

Comment: Most database libraries only allow you to execute one query per call...basically, the problem PA's answer is addressing.

Answer (score 1):

Your code assumes that there is only one statement in the file.

You may either (1) parse the statements to execute them sequentially, or (2) execute the file with an external invocation of the mysql command.

#### 1. parsing

Parsing the statements looks like a simple task, something along

```
$sqltxt = file_get_contents("setup.sql");
$statements = explode(";", $sqltxt);
foreach($statements as $stmt){
   @mysql_query($stmt)
}
```

but beware because it is easy to get caught by internal commands, embedded semicolons and other traps.

#### 2. external command

it looks easy, too

```
$command = 'mysql --user=usr1 --password=secret --database=db --execute="SOURCE setup.sql"';
$res = shell_exec($command);
```

but again can get caught accomodating to the appropiate  command in a cross platform way.

Comment: I may seem quite stupid by saying this, but how would I go about executing the above?

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you're trying to pull off here, but if you are attempting to validate if the table exists before creating it the T-SQL would go like this..

```html
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.tables WHERE name='users') 
 CREATE TABLE users (
  'id' INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  username varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  email varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  password varchar(255) NOT NULL)

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.tables WHERE name='details') 
 CREATE TABLE details (
  name varchar(255),
  server_ip varchar(255),
  store_link varchar(255),
  bans_link varchar(255))
```

Comment: Made a slight edit and removed IF NOT EXISTS. Still does not work

Comment: Define 'does not work', preferably with your expectations and any error message that is returned.

Comment: I have php errors enabled and it does not return any errors. When checking the table in the database it does not create any tables. Although, when there is only 1 CREATE TABLE it will create the table.

Comment: Ok.  My skills are SQL Server and not PHP, so at this point I'll withdraw from the question.  Good luck.